# Are TFS and salesforce compatible?

Tags: team-foundation-server, integration, source-control, salesforce

I am looking to see if TFS and salesforce will integrate. I want to use TFS for source control for my Apex classes, triggers, VS pages.

Would using the salesforce editor be a better choice to integrate the source control with than visual studios?

Please let me know whether this is possible. I'm trying to keep things streamlined :)

Comment: Please focus your question on specific capabilities that you need. Questions like "Which is better" are off-limits here.

Comment: Sure, The most specific capability i need to know is whether or not TFS version control will integrate with salesforce. The choice of the editor was an afterthought.

Comment: Thanks, but I should have been more clear. I don't want you to tell _me_ -- I don't know anything about TFS or Salesforce, so I can't help you. I'm encouraging you to [edit] your question to make it sound less subjective (i.e., asking for an opinion).

Answer (score 2):

It appears that it's possible to use TFS with Salesforce, however, judging by the lack of google results, I'd say it's not as prominent as git.  [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjw3NwxudsQ) demo of someone using TFS with Salesforce.

If you go the git route, check out [haoide](https://github.com/xjsender/haoide), which installs on top of SublimeText3.  It's a great ide and the developer is very active and always improving the features.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce DX has allowed users to use any source control system as a source of truth for their development.

In case you are facing issues with the DEFAULT repo of TFS, then I would suggest that create a private git repo in TFS and pull all meta data from your concerned org and you should be good off.

In short TFS source control system can be used to store salesforce

Answer (score 0):

On the question of TFS integration, the answer is yes.  I have used TFS 2015-2018 and Salesforce for over 5 years in multiple-org development efforts.  You can associated a set of Salesforce changes to a User Story, Task, Bug or any Work Item in TFS, completing product lifecycle configuration management.  Note that you will need to use TFVC over Git for this granular agile integration - For Salesforce is well worth it. Git still works under TFS with de facto Git capabilities.  Both types of source control allow for conflicts and merging for multiple developers in an Org which is a *must* for multi-developer-Orgs. Branching of change sets become very useful when deploying changes across Orgs.  As Raja mentioned, there is functionality overlap with Salesforce DX in this capability so you have choices here.

You need an IDE for integration.  Popular choices in no particular order are Eclipse + Force.com plug-in + TFS plug-in and IntelliJ IDEA community edition + Illuminated Cloud 2, among others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TFS for Salesforce code repository. We are using it at my Bank. You would

1. create a git repository within TFS.
2. Create or clone a local git from origin (TFS)
3. Get your metadata and classes ready using ANT tool or other migration tool using package.xml
4. Push local branch to TFS using git push
   Done